# How to unzip any (zip)file that is IFormFile property using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, file-upload, iformfile

My scenario is Client side will upload a zipped file.

Then in the back-end asp.net core, the file is retrieve as IFormFile.

How do I extract this IFormFile and pick a specific file inside it?

Comment: My code snippet provide a feature to extract a specific file from an uploaded zip file, and save the specific file into local folder. Did I misunderstand in some place sir?

Comment: If you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer to end this case? And if you have any further issue you can also share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you may take [ZipArchive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_IO_Compression_ZipArchive__ctor_System_IO_Stream_) package into consideration. Pls install this package first to try my code snippet`<PackageReference Include="System.IO.Compression" Version="4.3.0" />`

Here's my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(FileModel file)
        {
            var stream = file.myfile.OpenReadStream();
            var archive = new ZipArchive(stream);
            ZipArchiveEntry innerFile = archive.GetEntry("code.txt");
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\files", "code.txt");
            innerFile.ExtractToFile(filePath);
            return Ok();
        }
```

And this is my test view:

```
@model WebAppMvc.Models.FileModel

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <dl>
        <dt>
            <label asp-for="myfile"></label>
        </dt>
        <dd>
            <input asp-for="myfile" type="file">
            <span asp-validation-for="myfile"></span>
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <input asp-page-handler="Upload" class="btn" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And my model looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebAppMvc.Models
{
    public class FileModel
    {
        public IFormFile myfile { set; get; }
    }
}
```